# Error: No provider for HttpClient! Angular error message

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I have some test code (Testing.ts) that in it has the following code segment:

```
let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
    TestService
])
var myInstance = new myTest(injector.get(TestService));
```

TestService.ts has the following code:

```
@Injectable()
export class TestService {

protected basePath = '/test/ ';
public defaultHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
public configuration = new Configuration();

    constructor(protected httpClient: HttpClient, @Optional()@Inject(BASE_PATH) basePath: string, @Optional() configuration: Configuration) {
        if (basePath) {
            this.basePath = basePath;
        }
        if (configuration) {
            this.configuration = configuration;
            this.basePath = basePath || configuration.basePath || this.basePath;
        }
    }
```

I used `tsc` to compile Testing.ts into testing.js and ran `node testing.js`
Running the code I received the error message: `Error: No provider for HttpClient! (TestService -> HttpClient)`. In TestService I have:

```
import {
HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams,
HttpResponse, HttpEvent
} from '@angular/common/http';
```

In api.module.ts I have:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders, SkipSelf, Optional } from 
'@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Configuration } from './configuration';
import { TestService } from './api/test.service';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, CommonModule,
      HttpClientModule ],
  declarations: [],
  exports:      [],
  providers: [
    TestService ]
    })
```

And in Testing.ts I have: `import { TestService } from '../api/api';`

From what I understand with this project structure using the import statements the injector should have no problem creating an instance of HttpClient for the constructor of TestService. Running angular ^4.3.0 on windows. Am I missing something? All help would be appreciated!

Comment: Anywy where this error is comming from? From `ReflectiveInjector` or missing dependency upon TestService creation.

Comment: I did just to be certain, but according to the documentation I shouldn't need to (It's registering as an unused import for that reason).

Comment: Unused import is when you import something and you don't use it **directly** in the code, so your reasoning is wrong here I think.

Comment: The error is coming from the 'ReflectiveInjector'. And good point regarding the import, but the statement is there regardless.

Comment: it just dont know how to/from where aquire http client since httpclientmodule is unknown to it. What is the reasoning behind all of this? Can;t you follow angular's testing convention using `TestBed` ??

Comment: Looking more closely I assume my problem is that I am trying to use angular outside of the context of an angular app which means I am probably missing some of the start up work that is automatically done when you generate a new angular app. Would there be any way to use angular as a dependency manager/framwork outside of an angular application?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem HttpClient is Angular's mechanism for communicating with a remote server over HTTP.

To make HttpClient available everywhere in the app,

open the root AppModule,
import the HttpClientModule symbol from @angular/common/http,
add it to the @NgModule.imports array.
Add the following to app.module.ts:

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; 
After that add in the import section like import:[HttpClientModule,  ]

This procedure is explained in the documentation

Comment: Not sure what changes you are suggesting. Look at my api.module.ts file. It has all of those imports already and I am using that as my root.